# How to resolve Django model form does not saving

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-forms

Hello I am trying to implement a Django model form when I try to now submit the form it does not save my data can I please get help I do not know where I can be going wrong with this implementation:

**Code Below: models.py**

```
class Videos(models.Model):

    lecturer = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
    module = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to='lectures/')
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
```

**Code Below: form.py**

```
class LectureVideos(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model= Videos
        fields = '__all__'
```

**Code Below:view.py**

```
def LectureVideoForm(request):

    form = LectureVideos()


    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('upload-success')



    return render(request, 'forms.html', {'form':form})
```

**Code Below:forms.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}

        <input type="submit" value="Upload Video">
    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You never passed the data to the form.

Comment: Sorry I am new to Django how to do you pass the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never passed the data to the form. In case of a POST request, you pass the `request.POST` (and `request.FILES`) to the form:

```
def LectureVideoForm(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LectureVideos(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('upload-success')
    else:
        form = LectureVideos()
    return render(request, 'forms.html', {'form':form})
```

---

> **Note**: Functions are normally written in *snake_case*, not *PerlCase*, therefore it is
> advisable to rename your function to `lecture_video_form`, not <s>`LectureVideoForm`</s>.